# how to make a array.map collapsible? I tried using bootstrap but I didn't get what I wanted even with trying dynamic id's. Can you help me(typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make a array.map collapsible. I tried using bootstrap but I didn't get what I wanted even with trying dynamic id's. Can you help me?(I'm using typescript)make an array showing collapsible

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean by "collapsible", are you talking about `.flatMap()`? ([flatMap documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap))

Comment: Can you add the code you attempted, so we can provide solution based off it.